# cisco 7200 vlan

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-7200

I have cisco 7200 with 4 interfaces. Gi0/1 is my WAN where the ISP is sending me untagged and tagged traffic. Gi0/3 is my LAN interface.

Now I have vlan ID `2402`. This vlan come from Gi0/1 and I want to resend it to Gi0/3. How can I do this?

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
 no shutdown
 encapsulation dot1Q 2402
!  
interface GigabitEthernet0/3.1
 no shutdown
 encapsulation dot1Q 2402
!
```

How I connect these interfaces ? There is no `switchport` command....

Comment: Thank  you for aksing; why are you using a router (i.e. 7200) instead of a switch?  What kind of 7200 NPE are you using?  What IOS and what feature set?  How much bandwidth is required for vlan 2402?  Please consider adding a few [more details](http://tinyurl.com/ne-checklist/) to your question.

Comment: I had specific traffic from my ISP.

Cisco 7206VXR (NPE-G1) processor (revision B) with 983040K/65536K bytes of memory.
SB-1 CPU at 700MHz, Implementation 1025, Rev 0.2, 512KB L2 Cache
6 slot VXR midplane, Version 2.0

Cisco IOS Software, 7200 Software (C7200-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is best done with a *bridge*.  Add the vlan tagged subinterface and the internal LAN interface to a bridge group, and it should work the way you want. (I've not done this for a long time. You're building an ethernet switch out of routed interfaces. This is the same thing done on a Cat-2948G-L3 -- I've seen CCIE's stumped by it until they get that it's a 48 port *router*.)

Another path would be policy routing. But I'm assuming the tagged traffic is not something that would be easily routed. (say, multicast IPTV traffic.)

Comment: He needs a switch, not a router in bridge mode.  It's crazy to attempt this on an NPE-G1 (i.e. software forwarding), when basic GigE switches that offload switching to HW are so inexpensive.

Comment: Mike, I will replace a router to switch in near furure. Currently solusion is temporary for 1-2 weeks only. Ricky's solution works perfectly :)

Comment: "When all you have is a hammer, *everything* is a nail." (said by one who has used a Bay Networks 16-port desktop *hub* as a hammer. 18ga steel case!)